# How to separate every two lines with awk

Tags: linux

I have this file.txt:

```
     Edward
     Lisa
     James
     Karine
     Jhone
     Kathrine
```

and i just want to make a skip after each two lines and replace the skips with hyphens (-----)

Output desired:

```
     Edward
     Lisa
     --------------
     James
     Karine
     --------------
     Jhone
     Kathrine
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried and What is the problem then

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply in `awk` by keeping a counter and when it reaches `2` output your separator line and reset the counter to zero. Your second rule just prints the current line and increments the counter, e.g.

```bash
awk 'n==2 {print "--------------"; n=0} {print; n++}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file named `file`, the output from the `awk` command above would be:

```
Edward
Lisa
--------------
James
Karine
--------------
Jhone
Kathrine
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed:

```bash
$ sed '3~2i --------------' file.txt
Edward
Lisa
--------------
James
Karine
--------------
Jhone
Kathrine
```

Starting with the third line, **i**nsert a line of dashes before that line and every 2nd line following.

Answer (score 0):

If prefer to try with AWK, i feel this could work and print the name in oneline.

`awk '{ if (lastline) {print lastline,$0;lastline=""}else {lastline=$0;next}}'`